# How do I use gpg --pinentry-mode loopback in a bash script?

Tags: bash, gnupg

When decrypting a file, if I use any method other than `--pinentry-mode loopback` I get the following error.

```
gpg: public key decryption failed: Permission denied
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I would like to decrypt the pgp file using a bash script but pinentry-mode requires user input. Is there a way to use `--pinentry-mode loopback` in a bash script without requiring manual user input?

Comment: I voted to move this question to superuser.com. Because this question has nothing to do with software development.

Comment: @Cyrus Genuine question. Is writing bash scripts not considered development?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the solution posted below is not secure since the passphrase will be in plaintext. You can use `--pinentry-mode loopback` in a bash script by combining it with `--passphrase-fd 0` which tells gpg to expect the passphrase from STDIN.

```
echo "yourpassphrase" | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --pinentry-mode loopback --output somefile.txt --decrypt somefile.txt.gpg
```

To make this more secure you would need to acquire your passphrase by a more secure means like retrieving it from a secret management system (HashiCorp Vault or similar).

Comment: The rub is `echo "yourpassphrase"` means it will be part of the shell environment and potentially able to be compromised on a multi-user system. (not to mention likely permanently part of the `history` file). Though not the crux of the question, a necessary consideration.